# Which checkbox is selected and assigning a value

Tags: php

I am trying to create logic to see what checkbox is selected (of 5 possible checkboxes) and if it is selected assign it a value of 0. if it is not selected I was to assign it a value of 1. The proceeding code snippet highlight this but throws a parse error in my else statement and I cannot fighure out why.
    //Check to see what checkbox is marked for correct answer

```
//Correct answer variables
$chkBox1 = 'unchecked';
$chkBox2 = 'unchecked';
$chkBox3 = 'unchecked';
$chkBox4 = 'unchecked';
$chkBox5 = 'unchecked';

if (isset($_POST['chkBox1'])) {

if ($chkBox1 == 'chkBox1Selected') {
$chkBox1 = '0';
                }
else{
$chkBox1 = '1';
}
}//End of chkBox1Selected logic
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a quiz. If so, there are better approaches than this one, as you can incorporate loops to simplify things considerably.

Comment: @nickb The start of your comment rather annoyingly reminded me of the MS Office paperclip.

Answer (score 0):

You don't understand how checkboxes work. If a checkbox is deselected before posting, it will *not* be set on post.

Therefore, the only condition that will *ever* be present in your code is that every value will show as `1`, since they cannot be overridden.

Take this snippet and try it out. It dynamically loops for the amount of variables you need and assigns the values based upon the submitted value.

```
$_POST['chkBox4'] = 'test';

for( $i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++ )
{
    $name = 'chkBox' . $i;
    $$name = !isset( $_POST[$name] ) ? 0 : $_POST[$name];
}

print $chkBox2 . ' // '. $chkBox4;
```

http://codepad.org/51RotnCf

Answer (score -2):

Ok I got it to work from a syntax standpoint, however now no matter what is selected it is still assigning a value of 1 to all the checkboxes and not changing the selected checkbox to a value of 0. Here is the new code that is correct from a syntax standpoint but defaults to 1 no matter what:

//Check to see what checkbox is marked for correct answer

```
//Correct answer variables
$chkBox1 = '1';
$chkBox2 = '1';
$chkBox3 = '1';
$chkBox4 = '1';
$chkBox5 = '1';

if (isset($_POST['chkBox1'])) {

if ($chkBox1 == 'chkBox1Selected') {
$chkBox1 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox1Selected logic


if (isset($_POST['chkBox2'])) {

if ($chkBox2 == 'chkBox2Selected') {
$chkBox2 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox2Selected logic


if (isset($_POST['chkBox3'])) {

if ($chkBox3 == 'chkBox3Selected') {
$chkBox3 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox3Selected logic


if (isset($_POST['chkBox4'])) {

if ($chkBox4 == 'chkBox4Selected') {
$chkBox4 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox4Selected logic

if (isset($_POST['chkBox5'])) {

if ($chkBox5 == 'chkBox5Selected') {
$chkBox5 = '0';
}

}//End of chkBox5Selected logic
```

Comment: This should be a an edit or a comment on your original question and NOT an answer.